# Custom CursorAdapter, ListView is shifting

Tags: android, listview, adapter, simplecursoradapter

My class extends SimpleCursorAdapter. In that class I try to get CallLog into ListView (with three TextViews (number, name and date) and two ImageViews (which represents incoming and outgoing calls).

My code in OnCreate method:

```
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, "TYPE IN (\"1\",\"2\")", null, "DATE DESC");
    startManagingCursor(c);

    String[] from = new String[] {"number", "name" , "_ID" };
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.number, R.id.name, R.id.duration};
    listNotImported=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListOfNotImportedCalls);
    listNotImported.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    list1Adapter5 = new IconicAdapter5(this, R.layout.rownotimportedcalls, c, from, to);
    listNotImported.setAdapter(list1Adapter5);
```

My class:

```
class IconicAdapter5 extends SimpleCursorAdapter
{


    public IconicAdapter5(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) 
    {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    }
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent )
    {
        rowNotImported = super.newView(CallLog.this, c, parent);
        String duration= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("DURATION"));
        ((TextView)rowNotImported.findViewById(R.id.duration)).setText(duration);
        return (rowNotImported);
}
```

Columns "number", "name" , "_ID" works fine, everything is ok. but duration, and another columns, which I try to get from cursor (eg "duration") in newView method are shifting.
jwei512 from ThinkAndroid blog ( http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/ ) wrote about that, but I still dont understand how I can put into my view calculated columns, and another columns in newView method.

I'm confused, because I can not find solution on the internet.Please help me.

jwei512:
"Then you’ll notice some weird behavior – namely, that you’ll see the names start shifting as you scroll up and down the list. What happens is that if you don’t instantiate and place something into your TextView (basically to act as a place holder) then in your bindView method nothing gets bound to some of the TextViews and thus the shifting. So basically, if you see stuff shifting around in your lists, then that’s a big flag for make sure you are binding things to all of your views in both your newView and bindView methods."

XML representing my row:

```
    <TableLayout android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/myTable" android:id="@+id/myTable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:stretchColumns="0"
    android:shrinkColumns="yes">


    <TableRow>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>

    <ImageView  
    android:layout_width="20dp" 
    android:layout_height="20dp" 
    android:id="@+id/imageViewType">
    </ImageView>

    </TableRow>




    <TableRow>
    <LinearLayout>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/headerNumber"
    android:textColor="@color/white" 
    android:textSize="12sp" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>


    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/number"
    android:textColor="@color/white" 
    android:textSize="12dp" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    >
    </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
    <LinearLayout>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/headerDate"
    android:textColor="@color/white" 
    android:textSize="12dp" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </TextView>
    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:textColor="@color/white" 
    android:textSize="12dp" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" >
    </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow>
    <LinearLayout>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/headerDuration"
    android:textColor="@color/white" 
    android:textSize="12dp" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </TextView>
    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/duration"
    android:textColor="@color/white" 
    android:textSize="12dp" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" >
    </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>



    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: From what I understand is that you need to set _something_ to the views in the newView and bindView. Try setting duration TextView to an empty string for example (or a single whitespace) if you do not have any data to put there at either bindView or newView.

Comment: Thanks  Audrius , I did it like that (didnt help)
    
**if (duration == null)
duration=getText(R.string.unknown).toString();**

Comment: OK, can you explain what do you mean by "shifting"? Are items in listview changing positions sporadically or are listview item content views re-sizing while scrolling?

Comment: Eg. in first row I have values (name, phone, duration) JOHN, 5455454545, 43.   If i scroll down and go back to first page I will see diffrent values in first row. Sometimes it changes when i scroll whole page, sometime it changes faster.  Can it be that I have to declare everything in the array FROM?

Comment: You don't need to (although it is a good practice) to declare everything in query _from_ argument. Now I wouldn't waste any more time to make SimpleCursorAdapter implementation to work as it takes too much of your time, just implement CursorAdapter yourself or any other [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html). Btw, how does [jwei512](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/) example works for you, do you still get the same shifting issue?

Comment: jwei512 example works OK, but hi declared columns in FROM argument. When I try to add new columns- it is not working OK. Same problem.  I changed class to extends CursorAdapter and still have same problem.

Comment: It looks like SimpleCursorAdapter is useful only for simple logic (-.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I really unerstand you question, but convinient place to make all calculations is overriden method setViewText()

```
private class MyCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {



    private Date d = new Date();

    @Override
    public void setViewText(TextView v, String text) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.TrackTime) {
            d.setTime(Long.parseLong(text));
            text = d.toLocaleString();
        }
        super.setViewText(v, text);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works with date (now I can declare it in FROM parameter) and convert from long to date. But what with columns which I cant declare (eg values represented  by images, eg call type?)

Comment: Take a look at documentation - there is also public void setViewImage (ImageView v, String value) method called when data is passed to ImageView

Comment: Could you take a look at my method? I read docs, but still cant to do working code. My values shifting again( when I put ImageView)  *** public void setViewImage (ImageView v, String value) 
     {
       if (v.getId() == R.id.imageViewType) 
          {
         if(value.equals("1") == true)
       value= "R.drawable.sym_call_incoming";
       if(value.equals("2") == true)
       value= "R.drawable.sym_call_outgoing";
         }
       super.setViewImage(v, value);

     }

Comment: Please add layout for list item.

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented through **bindView()** method since on updating the rows this method is called. If not then override that and again fetch data from database.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO to do it right:

1. bindView() is not necessary. use newView
2. Every value must be declared in String[] from.
3. if you want to make any operations on TextViews you should use setViewText(TextView v, String text) method (thanks piotrpo)

4.If you want do operations on ImageViews use that code (eg you want different images for incoming and outgoing calls)

```
class IconicAdapter5 extends SimpleCursorAdapter
{
    private int source = 0;

    @Override
    public void setViewImage (ImageView v, String value) 
    {
         if (v.getId() == R.id.imageViewType) 
            {
                 if(value.equals("1") == true)
                 {
                    source= (R.drawable.sym_call_incoming);
                 }

                 if(value.equals("2") == true)
                 {
                    source= (R.drawable.sym_call_outgoing);
                 }
             }
         v.setImageResource(source);
    }
```

}