# How to load information on listview from txt file

Tags: android, android-listview

I wish to load the information from the text file onto listview. Please help me with the same code.

The information I am getting while reading is in following format

```
1,demo,time,date:
2,sad,dad,sad:
```

I need to display the data in such a way that for int values say 0/1 there should be an image.
Next demo/sad below that time/dad and atlast date must be displayed. Please help me for the same.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? How to read file, how to parse this file, or how to put parsed data into listview? Where this file is located (apk, downloaded from web etc?

Comment: @StackOverflow Thank you for adding tags, but please make sure that they are relevant (on this particular question, it's a good one, but some of your other suggestions don't fit). Also, when a question has poor grammar, poor formatting, a poor title or other issues, please take the time to fix these as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override CursorAdapter.setViewText()

I answered similar question here:
[Custom CursorAdapter, ListView is shifting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429005/custom-cursoradapter-listview-is-shifting/6445805#6445805)

Another way is just simple if command while parsing your data.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking would require quite a lot of code to answer the question fully. Looking at your revised question, you should look into creating a custom Adapter by implementing the `ListAdapter` interface. For `ListViews` and `ArrayAdapters`, as well as creating your own custom adapters, [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) is pretty good.